# Android Studio Gradle Build Errors Java

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm starting Android App development. I've got a Nexus 6P running Android N and Android Studio is all setup and my phone is in debugging mode but when I "Run app" in Android Studio, I get these sort of errors:

```
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

The full log can be found here: http://pastebin.com/raw/kzxdqdwB

Answer (score 0):

**I was running and old version of JDK**